# GitHub / GitLab merge request and next commits

Tags: github, gitlab

I am new at GitLab and have some difficulties while using some features. Could you please clarify me about the following issues?

**1.** Do we create MR (merge request) by branch or by commit(s)? For example I create a branch called `issue-100` and then apply some commits to the branch. Then I push this branch to origin repo. In this scene I think we create MR for this `issue-100`. Is that true?

**2.** What if I make additional commit(s) to this branch (`issue-100`) and then push to the origin? In this case, should I create another MR or are these further commit(s) regarded as inside the first MR for this branch?

**3.** I create an issue that has an issue number #100. In this scene, when I use a branch called `issue-100` and then push it to remote repo and create MR, how can I make relation between this issue and MR?

Comment: did you try any of that? Did you read the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) ?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes amigo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. true, by branch
2. if MR remains open, new commits will be added to this MR
3. by hash with issue number: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#closing-issues-automatically

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. Are these and most of the behaviors related to merge, commit, branch, etc. the same or similar in Git and GitLab?

Comment: Git is just a version control system. Everywhere the same, including merges, commits, branches etc. GitLab is Git hosted on a server with some additional features connected with their UI. The whole concept of Merge Requests (or Pull Requests on GitHub) is GitLab stuff but the rest is just regular Git

Comment: Do you mean that the MR, commit, pull request, etc. are the same in GitHub and GitLab?